# RegionPlot3D of MeshRegion with VertexColor-like behavior

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, rendering

I regularly use the `VertexColors` option with `GraphicsComplex[]` to render images of objects with certain attributes at the vertices.

For example,

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
  GraphicsComplex[PolyhedronData["Cuboctahedron", "VertexCoordinates"],
   Polygon[PolyhedronData["Cuboctahedron", "FaceIndices"]],
   VertexColors -> 
    Table[{Opacity[Random[]], 
      Glow[Hue[Random[]]]}, {PolyhedronData["Cuboctahedron", 
       "VertexCount"]}]]},
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> None]
```

gives something like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have been experimenting with `MeshRegion`s for a few things (Somewhat related to this question: [Differential Geometry on a MeshRegion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78094/differential-geometry-on-a-meshregion)) since they allow me to attach attributes to the vertices in a more generic manner.

Sadly, `RegionPlot3D[]` doesn't seem to respect or use the `MeshCellStyle` directive:

```
bmr = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  PolyhedronData["Cuboctahedron", "VertexCoordinates"], 
  Polygon[PolyhedronData["Cuboctahedron", "FaceIndices"]], 
  MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> {PointSize[Large], Black}, 
    1 -> {Dashed, Thick, Blue}, 2 -> Opacity[0.5, Green]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but...

```
RegionPlot3D[bmr, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It isn't *precisely* clear to me what is available to `RegionPlot3D[region]` from the supplied *region* at render time. Any thoughts here?

(nb- I realize I *could* use the `BoundaryMeshRegion[]` output (`bmr` above) and just use `Show[]` to get the various camera angles, etc that I need. Like

```
Show[bmr, ViewPoint -> Front, Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {1, - 2, 3}}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but I suppose I'd like to understand a little bit about how `RegionPlot3D[]` does what it does with respect to `MeshRegion`s a little better)

Comment: I would guess that mathematically `RegionPlot3D` uses only the region defined by the mesh region and programmatically that means it uses only the polygons of the boundary.  Compare `First@Show@bmr` and `First@RegionPlot3D@bmr`.

Comment: You can post-process the `RegionPlot3D` output to add `VertexColors` to `Polygons`:, e.g. `rp=RegionPlot3D[bmr, Boxed -> False,Lighting -> "Neutral"];  rp /. Polygon[x_]:> ( Polygon[#,VertexColors->(RandomColor[Hue[_, 1, 1,RandomReal[{.5,1}]], Length@#, ColorSpace -> "RGB"] )] &/@x)`

Comment: Ah- also a good idea. I'm interested in the 'general solution' to this (if possible) since it would be cool to attach a bunch of qualia to the vertices / faces in the region and have the renderer be able to do things with that stuff 'on the fly' (I've been doing that with RenderMan shaders for eons, but would like to be able to do that in MMa, of course, GLSL shaders would be nice to add to MMa at some point too :)

Answer (score 1):

Coloring vertices can be colored by adding `VertexColors` after `RegionPlot`:

```
rplot = RegionPlot3D[bmr, Boxed -> False];

rplot /. GraphicsComplex[p_, rest__] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[p, rest, VertexColors -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[p[[All, 1]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]